# OpenMP truncating float

Tags: c++, openmp

I am reading a data *(1-dimensional/vector)* from a CSV file into a `float` array and applying ***Quick Sort*** on it:

```
int main()
{

float floatArr[2000];

ReadRandomData(floatArr, "D:\RandomData.csv");

//#pragma omp parallel
{
    QuickSort(floatArr, 0,2000);
}

for(int i=0; i<2000; i++)
{
    cout<<floatArr[i]<<endl;
}

_getch();

}
```

and output is something like this:

[image]

but once I uncomment the `#pragma omp parallel` part, output is something like this *(its truncating I think)*:

[image]

Can anyone explain me why is this happening with OpenMP and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Here is ***QuickSort*** part:

```
void QuickSort(float* arr, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int pivot = arr[startIndex];                    //pivot element is the leftmost element
    int splitPoint;

if(endIndex > startIndex)                        //if they are equal, it means there is only one element and quicksort's job here is finished
{
    splitPoint = Splitarr(arr, pivot, startIndex, endIndex);
                                                  //Splitarr() returns the position where pivot belongs to
    arr[splitPoint] = pivot;
    QuickSort(arr, startIndex, splitPoint-1);   //Quick sort first half
    QuickSort(arr, splitPoint+1, endIndex);  //Quick sort second half
}
```

}

and here is Splitting Code:

```
int Splitarr(float* arr, int pivot, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int leftBoundary = startIndex;
    int rightBoundary = endIndex;

while(leftBoundary < rightBoundary)            //shuttle pivot until the boundaries meet
{
     while( pivot < arr[rightBoundary]        //keep moving until a lesser element is found
            && rightBoundary > leftBoundary)      //or until the leftBoundary is reached
     {
          rightBoundary--;                      //move left
     }

            swap(arr[leftBoundary], arr[rightBoundary]);


     while( pivot >= arr[leftBoundary]        //keep moving until a greater or equal element is found
            && leftBoundary < rightBoundary)      //or until the rightBoundary is reached
     {
          leftBoundary++;                        //move right
     }

            swap(arr[rightBoundary], arr[leftBoundary]);

}

return rightBoundary;                             //leftBoundary is the split point because
                                                  //the above while loop exits only when 
                                                  //leftBoundary and rightBoundary are equal
}
```

Comment: What does `QuickSort` look like?

Comment: Can you also show your `swap` method?

Comment: @ScY Using the one given by C++ (std) by default. Issue isn't there I reckon as its swapping properly and list is sorted, just end result is truncating.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were using your own. It should be noted that parallelization of that one function isn't doing much, since you are only calling it once.

Comment: Please 1) Do not post text as images, post as text instead 2) Post code in form of a [mcve]. 3) Your parallelization makes no sense, you cannot just add `pragma omp parallel` and expect the code to be correct but faster. Whave you spent any thoughts on the parallelization at all? You might be best off starting with a [book](http://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-books/) or [tutorial](http://www.openmp.org/resources/tutorials-articles/) about OpenMP.

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing in your algorithm which I assume is causing the problem.

Change line:

```
int pivot = arr[startIndex];
```

to

```
float pivot = arr[startIndex];
```

Converting float to int truncates the decimals, as you correctly presumed. That might solve your issue.

Comment: I also tried it with int pivot and not parallelized. There were still some truncated elements. Fewer than with parallelization enabled, but still.

Comment: I think it would be due to `arr[splitPoint] = pivot;` but all are truncated for case of OpenMP makes me wonder

Comment: The answer may have a point, but misses the fact that the entire parallelization is is completely bogus / broken.

Comment: @Zulan Thanks for review - it would be even nicer, if you suggest how to fix this completely bogus parallelization?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan [This should do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Parallelization)

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I don't see how you even intended to approach parallelization - fixing that would amount to start from scratch. Teaching fundamentals is off-topic for SO.